# What's the best way to asynchronously load data into a Data Grid View?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, forms

This code allows the form to load before the data is loaded but some of the components on the form such as buttons and the datagridview itself are "invisible" until the data is loaded.

How do I fix this problem?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
        {
            this.Invoke(new MyDelegate(delegate()
            {               
                ReadXml(path);
                Bind();
           }));              
        }));

        t.Start();
     }

    private void Bind()
    {
        dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
    }
```

I also have this other code which works better, but requires that I use 2 new threads. This can't be the best way to do this, can it?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
          {
              this.Invoke(new InvokeDelegate(delegate()
              {
                  Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
                  {
                      ReadXml(path);
                  }));
                  t2.Start();
                  t2.Join();
                  Bind();
              }));
          }));

        t.Start();
    }
```

Comment: if this is the *only* code that runs on form loading, everything should work perfectly and smoothly, imo. There is something esle, at this point, that blocks your UI. Check it out...

Comment: **Or** I see the `Bind()` method, if that method actually puts the data on UI, *that* could be a blocking call.

Comment: that's all I have in my Form1_Load event handler procedure. Bind() just does this: dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

Comment: the thread is unnecessary here. All it is going to do is post back to the message loop to do the invoke which will end up back on the UI thread. That means it cant run until Form1_Load (on the UI thread) returns anyway.

Comment: I don't know how the thread can be unnecessary. when i get rid of it the form won't load until ReadXML() returns

Comment: It is always the same controls that don't show until the t finishes?  That is just strange.

Comment: Just noticed you are using Invoke. Use BeginInvoke instead. Invoke is synchronous, BeginInvoke will post back and is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use BeginInvoke() instead of an Invoke() the code in the delegate will be executed on the current UI thread but it wont happen until after all the current UI work pending finishes (like the current Form1_Load invocation). Invoke is a synchronous call so that's why you needed the thread.

```
   void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new MyDelegate(delegate()
        {
            ReadXml(path);
            Bind();
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Try to offer some explanation for your answer instead of just providing a code block. It will help other users to understand the answer instead of correcting a localized problem. Thanks!

Comment: good point, I didn't bother because it was in the comments above but I can see where someone wouldn't necessarily drill into them

Answer (score 2):

A form timer (not system timer) will let all other messages process before it fires.

Just give it an interval of like 100-250 milliseconds; 
Set it to enabled=false in the designer;
Set it to enabled=true in the form_load event.
In the timer_tick event make the first line timer.enabled = false.
After that (still in the tick event) load your grid.