# How do I prevent window lock when binding large dataset to grid in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I've got a window that will be filled with a grid.  On a background thread I asynchronously retrieve data tables from several different servers.  These tables I then need to display in the grid.  I have a progress bar from the background thread displaying while I'm establishing connections and pulling the data, but when the grid is being filled the UI thread is (understandably) blocked.  Therefore, the progress bar stalls and it looks like the window is frozen.  Filling the grid can take anywhere from 20 seconds to 2 minutes depending on the data set (Yes, it's huge; No, I can't make it smaller sadly.)

What I want to know is without using any Linq or custom libraries how can I bind the data without blocking the UI (keep the progress bar moving), then display the whole thing in one go?

I don't necessarily require concrete code, but more "This is what to do" with some logic behind it.

The key, really, is to load the data into the grid while not blocking the UI thread so a progress indicator can be displayed (and active) while it is ongoing.

Thank you all!

Comment: this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11976418/whats-the-best-way-to-asynchronously-load-data-into-a-data-grid-view

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms asynchronous loading large data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500613/winforms-asynchronous-loading-large-data)

Comment: That's pretty close but unfortunately not quite.  It does nicely explain how to asynchronously load the data but the UI thread is still blocked while that occurs, which I'm trying to avoid, or at least make it very minimal.

Comment: Does a CPU core get fully loaded when UI hangs? If not, it looks like you've pulled references to data, which get synchroneously pulled when accessed.

Comment: Yes, a core gets fully loaded.  I assume that's the UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `VirtualMode=true;` and then you can handle the `CellValueNeeded` event

here an example explaining how to do it
[Implementing Virtual Mode with Just-In-Time Data Loading in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171624(v=vs.90).aspx)

also, you can refer to this [Performance Tuning in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171621(v=vs.90).aspx)

hope it will help you

Comment: Aha yes thank you, I think that's exactly what's needed.