# Waiting form issues Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I’ve been running over some lines of code for a while now and I’d be really grateful if you could give me a hand. I’m trying to create a “waiting” form that shows up every time I execute any method that takes long time to process. I’ve created the class IDisposable “Espera” as follows:

```
public class Espera : IDisposable
{
    FrmEspera fEspera;
    

    public Espera(string texto = "Espere...")
    {
        Task.Run(async () => await mostrarFormulario(texto));
    }

    private async Task mostrarFormulario(string texto)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            fEspera = new FrmEspera();
            fEspera.Texto = texto;
            fEspera.ShowDialog();
        });
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
           
            fEspera?.InvokeIfRequired(() => fEspera.Dispose());

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);

        }
        catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            Log.Instance.Error($"Error AgregateException Espera => {ae.Message}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Instance.Error($"Exception Espera => {ex.Message}");
        }

    }
}
```

Problem is that sometimes, when I call the form, the message box appears below it and even when I click accept, the form keeps on running instead of closing (like the dispose order wasn’t executed). What am I missing here?

```
          using (new Espera("Aplicando reglas al perfil..."))
            {
                await miMetodo();
            }

            MessageBox.Show(“OK”);
```

Comment: Any time you  create and display forms from a different thread, you're bound to get weird and unexpected behavior.  Just don't do that.  Create and display the "waiting" form from the same thread as the UI interface...

Comment: The thing is that I was doing it in the UI interface, and it works, but when the invoke takes place to fill the data grid in the UI thread, the waiting form (a gif animation) freezes until the action is completed. Is there a way for the gif to keep on working being in the UI thread?

Comment: Possibly you just need to approach the [loading of your grid differently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29219786/2330053)?

Comment: This link can provide a perfect solution:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yZYAaScEsc0. Don't forget to upvote if this works! :)

Comment: Please never ever EVER call `Application.DoEvents()`. It's only in the framework for backward compatibility with VB6 app upgrades. It is evil in how it interrupts the application message pump. It will eventually cause you bugs that you will not easily be able to debug.

Comment: The winforms UI is very responsive so long as you push all non-trivial processing to a non-UI thread. That's what you MUST learn to do.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I fixed the issue creating the form in the constructor.

```
    public Espera(string texto = "Espere...")
    {
        fEspera = new FrmEspera();
        Task.Run(async () => await MostrarFormulario(texto));
    }
```

and returning a DialogResult in the task.

```
    public async Task<DialogResult> MostrarFormulario(string texto = "Espere...")
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            fEspera.Texto = texto;
            return fEspera.ShowDialog();
        });
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please do not do this. Do NOT create, access, or update any UI elements from a non-UI thread. This most definitely includes any code in a `Task.Run`. You are OK to push any processing you have to do to a non-UI thread, but you must ALWAYS ensure you do NOT create, access, or update any UI elements.

Comment: I'd be very pleased to follow your advice if you could just tell me how I should do it. Thank you.

Comment: You know how to do `Task.Run`. Just don't create, access, or update any UI elements in the `Task.Run`. What more do you need to know?